# Why does changing a copy of an argument change the argument?

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, object

I have a function to generate a random map given a number of tiles, a starting map, and the type of grid (triangular,square,hex) to use.  It returns an array of tiles, `map`, with two extra properties: `seed`, the starting map used, and `adjy`*.  Initially, `map` is set to equal `seed`.  For some reason, `map.seed` does not equal the `seed` argument.  Instead, `map.seed` equals `map`.  I figured out that `seed` is changed by `map.push()`.  I have tried `"use strict";`, using `arguments[1]` instead of `seed`, and moving the statement `map.seed=seed;` around (these didn't have any effect).  The code doesn't have any errors in jsHint and doesn't throw any in the console.

*`adjy` is short for adjacency, and is 0 for triangles, 1 for squares, and 2 for hexagons.

I have prepared a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hacatu/gLM9X/2/) and the code is also below:

```
console.clear();
var canvas=document.getElementById('canvas'),
    ctx=canvas.getContext('2d');
canvas.width=window.innerWidth;
canvas.height=window.innerHeight;
ctx.translate(canvas.width/2,canvas.height/2);
Array.prototype.equals=function(a){//array1==array2 is broken, create substitute
    return this.length==a.length&&this.every(
        function(e,i){
            return e instanceof Array?
                a[i]instanceof Array&&e.equals(a[i]):
                !(a[i]instanceof Array)&&e==a[i];
        }
    );
};
Array.prototype.includes=function(n){
    return this.some(
        function(e){
            return n instanceof Array?
                n.equals(e):
                n==e;
        }
    );
};
function Map(tiles,seed,adjy){
    if(!arguments.length)return [];
    if(arguments.length<2)
        if(tiles)seed=[[0,0]];
        else return [];
    if(arguments.length<3)
        if(tiles<seed.length)return adjy;//returns undefined
        else adjy=1;
    var map=seed,cdd=[],nos=//candidate tiles,Neighbors Of Square (or tile)
        [[[0,1,-1],[1,0,0]],//triangle
         [[0,1,0,-1],[1,0,-1,0]],//square
         [[0,1,1,0,-1,-1],[1,0,-1,-1,0,1]]][adjy];//hex
    function addAdj(p){//adds adjacent tiles to candidates (cdd)
        var c;
        for(var i=0;i<nos[0].length;i++)
            if(!cdd.includes(
               c=[p[0]+nos[0][i],p[1]+nos[1][i]])&&
               !map.includes(c))
                  cdd.push(c);
    }
    function pickR(){//pick a random tile
        var p=cdd.splice(
            ~~(Math.random()*cdd.length),1)[0];//~~ is the same as floor
        addAdj(p);
        map.push(p);//the line where the problem happens
    }
    seed.forEach(addAdj);
    while(tiles>map.length)pickR();
    map.seed=seed;
    map.adjy=adjy;
    return map;
}
function drawMap(map){
    if(!map.hasOwnProperty('adjy'))return void 0;
    function draw0(c){
        var x=c[0],y=c[1];
        ctx.beginPath();
        switch((x+y)%2){
            case 0:
                x*=5;y*=7;
                ctx.moveTo(x,y);
                ctx.lineTo(x-5,y+7);
                ctx.lineTo(x+5,y+7);
                break;
            default:
                x*=5;y*=7;
                ctx.moveTo(x,y+7);
                ctx.lineTo(x+5,y);
                ctx.lineTo(x-5,y);
        }
        ctx.closePath();
        ctx.fill();
    }
    function draw1(c){
        var x=c[0],y=c[1];
        ctx.fillRect(x*10,y*10,10,10);
    }
    function draw2(c){
        var x=c[0]*7,y=c[1];
        x+=y*3.5;
        y*=7.5;
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.moveTo(x,y);
        ctx.lineTo(x,y+5);
        ctx.lineTo(x+3.5,y+7.5);
        ctx.lineTo(x+7,y+5);
        ctx.lineTo(x+7,y);
        ctx.lineTo(x+3.5,y-2.5);
        ctx.closePath();
        ctx.fill();
    }
    switch(map.adjy){
        case 0:
            map.forEach(draw0);
            break;
        case 1:
            map.forEach(draw1);
            break;
        default:
            map.forEach(draw2);
    }
}
var board=new Map(37*6,[[-5,0],[5,0]],2);
console.log(board.seed);
drawMap(board);
```

I have included all of the code in case the problem is not in fact that `seed` is updated when `map` is, though my developer console tests suggest this.

Comment: Unrelated to the question, but worth noting: ES6 (the next version of the JavaScript language standard) will likely include a `Map` constructor, so you may want to rename yours to avoid future compatibility issues.

Comment: `var map=seed` if seed is an array (or object), map will be *the same* array (not a copy). Maybe that's the problem? Sorry, but I couldn't figure out the whole code.

Comment: If you want a copy, use `var map = seed.slice(0)`

Comment: Can't see the problem but that code is torture to read, whitespace is free.

Comment: And curly braces are on sale this week. :)

Comment: @bfavaretto: Yes! That worked. Thanks, I did _not_ want to make map the same array; I didn't think that was possible.  Apparently the problem wasn't related to `seed` being an argument.  For the record, using `map=new Array(seed);` works too.

Comment: `map=new Array(seed)` is different; there, `map[0] === seed`. But in `map = seed.slice(0)`, `map[0] === seed[0]`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assigning an array or object does *not* make a copy of it.

```
var map = seed;
```

makes the two variables reference the *same* array. As a result, any changes you make to the array via one variable will be seen through the other. If you want a copy, you have to do it explicitly:

```
var map = seed.slice(0);
```