# Javascript: How do I pass the value (not the reference) of a variable to a function?

Tags: javascript, closures, pass-by-reference, pass-by-value

Here is a simplified version of something I'm trying to run:

```
for ( winDoorNo = 0; winDoorNo < aWinDoorSetSpec.no_of_winDoors; winDoorNo ++ ) {
    (function (winDoorNo, self) {

        self.tangentVectors_azimuth = [];
        self.tangentVectors_polar   = [];

        self.tangentVectors_azimuth[winDoorNo] = tangentPlane.tangentVector_azimuth;
        self.tangentVectors_polar[winDoorNo]   = tangentPlane.tangentVector_polar;

    })(winDoorNo, this);
}
```

but I'm finding that the `self.tangentVectors_azimuth` array only contains a value on the last value that the for loop index variable had. I found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2568966/how-do-i-pass-the-value-not-the-reference-of-a-js-variable-to-a-function) describing a similar problem and I implemented the suggested solution which is to use a closure. However this does not work for me. After the for loop has executed, the value of `this.tangentVectors_azimuth` is still:

```
[undefined, undefined, Object { x=0.01999999996662183, y=0.01599999957331022, z=0, more...}]
```

Comment: `.slice(0)` will shallow clone an array. If you want to deep clone it implement the logic yourself.

Comment: If you *were* able to pass the object as a value, what effect would it have? You're not returning anything from that function, or otherwise doing anything with the "self" parameter after you alter its contents.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why does changing a copy of an argument change the argument?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18245208/why-does-changing-a-copy-of-an-argument-change-the-argument)

Comment: @Barmar, Benjamin: That doesn't seem to be the problem the OP has. Even his closure "solution" doesn't hit the reason.

Comment: You only need to create a closure if you're referencing the iteration variable in an asynchronous callback. You're just assigning normal variables, I don't see why you need to do anything special.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are creating new arrays for each iteration in the loop, so each time you will throw away the previous result.

Create the arrays outside the loop:

```
this.tangentVectors_azimuth = [];
this.tangentVectors_polar = [];
for (winDoorNo = 0; winDoorNo < aWinDoorSetSpec.no_of_winDoors; winDoorNo++) {
  this.tangentVectors_azimuth[winDoorNo] = tangentPlane.tangentVector_azimuth;
  this.tangentVectors_polar[winDoorNo] = tangentPlane.tangentVector_polar;
}
```